# Can I ask question in Bangla here?

Tags: discussion

We are trying to build a question answer site for the history of Bangladesh in Bangla. Can we ask those questions in Bangla in this forum?

Comment: No, this is an English language site. However, you might check out Area 51 here (http://area51.stackexchange.com/) on the possibility of creating a beta site in another language.

Comment: The software used to run these sites are also (partly) open source, so you can start your own site using it.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, I failed to find the download link of the software. Could you please help?

Comment: Actually, Stack Exchange no longer makes their code available to other parties for the development of their own sites.

Comment: @OmarShehab Maybe try to use WikiMedia as forum?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. However, there are other softwares that do similar things, although not as good of course. @OmarShehab: Search for "Stackoverflow open source clone". Using a Wiki, like Voitcus explains, is also a possibility, but that's a very different type of software.

Comment: A stackexchange on Bangla language has been proposed in [AREA51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109460/bangla-or-bengali-language-learners).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is English-speaking forum. Of course English questions related to history of Bangladesh are accepted.

As a reference to Lennart Regebro's [comment](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/709/can-i-ask-question-in-bangla-here#comment2604_709), I'm afraid the code of Stack Exchange sites is closed (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14656/216937)). You might be interested also in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/216937) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30269/216937).

I'd like to invite you however to participate in this English site too :-)